# HttpUrlConnection connection reset error when sending second message

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, httpurlconnection

Basically that's all, the first message sent is correctly received by the server, but all the next ones fail. This is the main loop that iterates over the messages and treates some errors for debugging and logic of the code. The variable udc is my database connection, but it works fine so ignore it.

```
for (MessageOutModel message : messageOutModels) {
    HttpURLConnection connection = MakeConnection();
    Date currentMoment = new Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
    System.out.println("Sent message id: " + message.id);
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
            connection.getOutputStream());
    out.write(message.contenido);
    out.close();
    //os.write(message.contenido);
    System.out.println("Message sent");
    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("Connection message: " + responseCode);
    message.f_ultimo_intento = currentMoment;
    if (responseCode != 200) {
        message.intentos++;
        message.desc_error = "Connection error: " + responseCode
                + " Connection error message: " + connection.getResponseMessage() + "Response error:" +
                connection.getResponseMessage();
       udc.UpdateMessageOut(message);
       if (message.intentos == configModel.n_reintentos) {
           udc.InsertError("MAX_INTENTOS", "Se ha alcanzado el máximo número de " +                         "intentos para el id-ticket: " + message.id + "-" + message.ticket_number);
       }
    } else {
        message.desc_error = "";
        udc.UpdateMessageOut(message);
    }
    connection.disconnect();
}
```

There goes the method MakeConnection()

```
protected HttpURLConnection MakeConnection() throws IOException {
    QName q = new QName(SERVER_URL, "");
    URL url = new URL(q.getNamespaceURI() + q.getLocalPart());
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    connection.setRequestProperty("UserName", Username);
    connection.setRequestProperty("PassWord", Password);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    return connection;
}
```

[Connection reset error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dw6CR.png)

Comment: Maybe you should try to move your connection outside the loop. Establishing connection with external services might be slowest part of the code execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end it resulted to be a firewall problem with the client and the server. It was blocking the connection for every other time after the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Use this as a quick solution.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = MakeConnection();

for (MessageOutModel message : messageOutModels) {
  // logic from your sample
}
connection.disconnect();
```

Also, you can use [try-with-resources](https://www.baeldung.com/java-try-with-resources) to improve design a little.

Comment: Thans for the try-with-resources, i will. About the forloop, we needed to make a connection for every request so, the structure is correct as it is,

Comment: Hmm.. Got it.
Maybe you need to create a service like `ConnectionManager` to prevent  'handshake-DDOS'? I'm not sure, but is it really so important to use new connection on each iteration? @m5m7n5